# How to move vectors under geom.Polygon.circular layer

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

The vectors are hidden by the geom.Polygon.circular, how do I move the vectors under layer of Circular?

- Circular is added like ol.Feature (localization)
- Vectors (points)

The Z-index for the vectors element does not change its position for the circular feature.

How do I solve this?

[image]

---

I need solution strictly for OSM OpenLayers and JavaScript

Comment: Are u using QGIS, ARCGis or?

Comment: No I'm using ol3 and osm in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Layers, in OpenLayers, are drawn in this order: **first** added is the one at the **bottom**.  Adding a **new layer** to the map adds it **on top** of the existing ones.

Try adding your polygon layer first, then your point layer.  If your features are in the same layer, then try separating them.